# Get request not working in CORS with NancyFX

Tags: c#, angular, cors, nancy

I'm having some problem with CORS request and NancyFx.
I've some GET request working but not everytime.

Since I use `Content-Type : application/json` my requests are "not simple type of request" so they have a preflight `OPTIONS` request.

The preflight works but sometimes the `GET` request following returns 404 (not finding the route i'm asking for) and sometime I get my data.

Here is my CORS response in Nancyfx :

```
protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer requestContainer, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
{
    base.RequestStartup(requestContainer, pipelines, context);

    pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((ctx) =>
    {
        ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH")
        .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
        .WithHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    });
}
```

The request I'm hitting look like this :

`http://localhost:3579/api/v2/vnos/{idVno:guid}/vnos` (and idVno is always set).

Here is what i get in console :

[image]

And here is what I get in the Network tab :

[image]

And the only specific header I'm adding in my client is the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` handler should be called on application startup, not request startup as you did, else it will be ignored if the request is not `2XX`.

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    pipelines.AfterRequest += (ctx) =>
    {
        ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH")
                    .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
                    .WithHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1422 for more informations.

Comment: only the snippet helped to resolve, forgot to add it on `4xx` response. thanks thought

Comment: This fixed my problem for me. I didn't know where to declare ApplicationStartup method. Later i found out that i had to create a class that extends DefaultNancyBootstrapper and NancyFx will assemblies with this reference and call it. Thank you!

Comment: For me it did'nt solve. Every request is catch by this block but I still having the CORS policy blocking return.